# Не работает setModelPath в ImageAi

Tags: python

Пытаюсь сделать туториал - https://medium.com/@guymodscientist/image-prediction-with-10-lines-of-code-3266f4039c7a
Скачал файл(resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5) и положил в папку с кодом,однако уже на первом же куске кода возникли проблемы и при запуске кода:

```
from imageai.Prediction import ImagePrediction
import os
execution_path = os.getcwd()
prediction = ImagePrediction()
prediction.setModelTypeAsResNet()
prediction.setModelPath( execution_path + "\resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5")
prediction.loadModel()
```

возникает ошибка ValueError: .

> ValueError: You have specified an incorrect path to the ResNet model file.

Я и провреял execution_path и даже попробовал в Google Collab,но все одно и тоже
С чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

```
import os

model_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5")
prediction.setModelPath(model_path)
```

Comment: Спасибо!Это помогло